# Boolean is not working correctly when trying to subtract a collection

Tags: modeling, modifiers

The models are very simple: it's a dice created entirely with the use of modifiers, and the holes I want to put in the dice are made with spheres that were replicated into arrays, then converted to meshes, and then I removed the spheres in excess.
[image]
[image]
[image]
I hid the collection to show the holes.
As you can see, only the last object is worked, which was the first that I did of the 3. The other 2 are copies, reworked.

**BLEND FILE:**
https://mega.nz/file/GW4l2YjA#pcQzawo0I38ptbmlAYEOzEm6noovJRTTV0ulYmaZiFU

Comment: The fast method doesn't like when there are coplanar faces. Try budging just a little bit your cutter objects in object mode, or use the exact solver

Comment: Tried it, not working.

Comment: Forgot to mention: tried also the precise method of course: no way.

Comment: It works out of the box in the blend file you provided. Make sure you use the latest stable blender version

Comment: I am on 2.92... I'll try to see if there's one newer.

Comment: Also in your file it's set to Object, maybe an oversight since in your screenshot it's set to collection, but setting it to collection solved the problem.